# Need suggestions implementing recursive logic in Hive UDF

Tags: hadoop, hive, bigdata, recursive-query

We have a hive table that has around 500 million rows. Each row here represents a "version" of the data and Ive been tasked to create table which just contains the final version of each row. Unfortunately, each version of the data only contains a link to his previous version. The actual computation for deriving the final version of the row is not trivial but I believe the below example illustrates the issue.

For example:

```
id | xreference
----------------
1  | null         -- original version of 1
2  | 1            -- update to id 1
3  | 2            -- update to id 2-1
4  | null         -- original version of 4
5  | 4            -- update to version 4
6  | null         -- original version of 6
```

When deriving the final version of the row from the above table I would expect the rows with ids 3, 5 and 6 to be produced.

I implemented a solution for this in cascading, which although is correct has an n^2 runtime and takes half a day to complete.

I also implemented a solution using giraffe which worked great on small data sets but I kept running out of memory for larger sets. With this implementation I basically created a vertices for every id and an edge between each id/xreference pair.

We have now been looking into consolidating/simplifying our ETL process and Ive been asked to provide an implementation that can run as a hive UDF. I know that Oracle provides functions for just this sort of thing but I haven't found much in the way of Hive functions.

Im looking for any suggestions for implementing this type of recursion specifically with Hive but Id like to hear any suggestions.

```
Hadoop 1.3
Hive 0.11
Cascading 2.2
12 node development cluster
20 node production cluster
```

Comment: Are `id` and `xreference` the only 2 columns you have?